Is the limit of $F(x)=x^{(x-1)^{(x-2)^{...^{(x-(x-1))}}}}$ equal to a tetration of 10 raised to 5.2629982...?
I've been experimenting with functions that grow super fast and I came across one in particular that I have been using Wolfram Alpha to compute the values for each x:
$$\displaystyle F(x)=x^{(x-1)^{(x-2)^{...^{(x-(x-1))}}}}$$
for all $x>1\wedge \>x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
For clarification, this is a power tower where each layer decreases starting at $x$ for a base and stopping at $1$. As $x$ approaches $\infty$, it appears to approach a power tower of $10$ with $x-3$ layers, all raised to the power of roughly $5.2629982...$ This implies that the limit of $F(x)$ is $(^{x-4}10)^{5.2629982...}$.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty^{-
}} F(x)=(^{x-4}10)^{5.2629982...}$$
Is there a way to prove or disprove this?
Note: The function F(x) cannot be put directly into Wolfram Alpha, so I have to enter the sequence manually such that $F(5)$ must be $5^{\Bigg(4^{\bigg(3^{\Big(2^{\big(1\big)}\Big)}\bigg)}\Bigg)}$. As I expand to $F(6)$ and thereafter, Wolfram Alpha's solution approaches $(^{x-4}10)^{5.2629982...}$.
Edit: For more clarification, I stuck to small $x$ since my method for entering $F(x)$ for each $x$ is quite redundant.
Update: I've been messing around with hypercalc and have discovered the origin of the irrational number following the tetration. $\log_{10}(183230.68388068094...)=5.2629982...$. The irrational decimal digits after $183230$ are due to the results of $F(x)$ for any large $x$ clearly not being an exact power of 10. I came to this conclusion by entering strings like30^29^28^...^3^2^1 (Equivalent of $F(30)$), and it returns $(^{x-3}10)^{183230.68388068094...}$ (Seen as [x-4] PT (183230.68388068094...) in the output, in my specific case, 26 PT (183230.68388068094...).)

You may be able to use Fold to nest the exponents

You mean surely that the right side is an asymptotic formula for $F(x)$. The limit for $x\to \infty$ does not exist.

I'll fix that. Let me know if I fix it incorrectly.

There is no need to add parenthesis. By consensus, the expression $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{\left(b^c\right)}$, so you can simply write $5^{4^{3^{2^1}}}$.

Instead, you missed some parenthesis in the general expression, since writing $x-1^{\bigg(x-2^{\Big(...^{\big(x-(x-1)\big)}\Big)}\bigg)}$ means $x-1$. There is where you should use parenthesis: $(x-1)^{(x-2) ^ \cdots}$

I wrote it that way because Wolfram assumes $a^{b^{c}}$ means $(a^{b})^{c}$.

I am pretty sure that Wolfram alpha considers $a^{b^c}$ to be $a^{(b^c)}$. $(a^b)^c$ is equal to $a^{bc}$ instead.

Try again: In Wolfram Alpha $2^{1^3}$ gives $2^{(1^3)} = 2$. If what you're saying were true, it would give $2^{1^3} = (2^1)^3 = 2^3 = 8$, but it doesn't.

I mean $(a^{b})^{^{c}}$

Power towers are calculated "from above" (or "from the right") per convention and Wolfram alpha knows that.

If in your original question, by $a^{b^c}$ you meant $(a^b)^c$ then, by the exponents law, $x^{(x-1)^{(x-2)^{...^{(x-(x-1))}}}} = x ^ {(x-1)!}$, which is much less interesting than a tower of exponents.

Actually, the time I did it may have been a bug on my part. You are correct. But on larger towers it can get buggy. (I did $15^{14^{13^{12^{11^{10^{9^{8^{...^{1}}}}}}}}}$ and that's where it occured.

this calculator helps you.

The calculator you provided has indeed helped. I'm pretty sure the iteration and 5.2629982... come from the fact that the overall power is $183230$, and $\log_{10}(183230)=5.2629965...$ which is pretty close. I believe the difference in value stems from the fact that the given values for $F(x)$ aren't flat powers of 10.

You realise that $1^\text{whatever} = 1$, right? :-)

That's why I stick to $x>1$. Besides, the 1 doesn't exactly matter given the power tower.

The iterated logarithm would be useful to read about here. The limit can be rewritten in terms of it.

This cannot be true. That 10 has to go up for large $x$.
